# How to convert a stereo MP3 to mono MP3

Tags: mp3, mono, sample-rate, bitrate, garageband

We had an MP3 created for a message greeting on our phone system. It is stereo MP3, not sure what the bit rate is, but is sampled at 44.1k.

Our sound system requires it to be in this format:

- 16 bit
- Mono
- 44.100 kHz

I have Garageband and went out to find Peak but they are out of business. Any ideas on how I might be able to convert my file?

Thank you!

Comment: Related - http://superuser.com/questions/325854/converting-a-bunch-of-mp3s-to-mono

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Download Audacity [here](http://www.audacityteam.org/download/). Also download the LAME MP3 library [here](http://lame1.buanzo.com.ar/)
2. Install Audacity on your system. Install the LAME MP3 library.
3. Open Audacity
4. Click on File > Open... and select the mp3 file in question
5. Click on Track > Stereo track to Mono
6. Click on File > Export. Choose "MP3 Files" as Format on the dropdown menu and click save.

   - Note 1: If you want to save in higher quality bitrate click on options and select the desired bitrate.
   - Note 2: As you click "Save" on the export menu it might ask you to locate the LAME MP3 Library. Just point it to wherever you have exported the file.

Peace

Answer (score 2):

On Linux systems like Ubuntu, you can use ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 -ac 1 output.mp3
```

where:

- `-c:a libmp3lame`: The audio codec to use
- `-q:a 2`: The audio quality (bitrate), see [LAME Bitrate Overview](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3)
- `-ac 1`: One audio channel

Comment: This is a far superior method to using Audacity, especially for those like me who have thousands of files to convert.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of tools. You can try Foobar2000 (which is a music player but can convert sounds too).

Comment: While I do believe this could be used to accomplish the task, if you could provide a little more details as to how it could be done with that tool, this answer would be far more beneficial.